# how to remove parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am trying to fetch data from MySQL Database using PHP and passing it on as JSON. When I try to display the response, it displays the error parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0. Can someone please help.
Below is my jQuery and PHP Code:

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#display").change(function()
    {
        var type = document.getElementById('display').value;
        alert(type);
        $.ajax(
        {
            //create an ajax request to load_page.php
            type: "GET",
            url: "DBOperations.php",
            data : "type=" +type,
            dataType: "json",  //expect text to be returned                
            success: function(response)
            {                  
                //$("#response").html(response); 
                //alert(response.);

                $.each(response, function(index, element)
                {
                    $('#response').html($(
                    {
                        text: element.name
                    }));
                });
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
try
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practice_db'; //your host and database name here.
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    //Connect to database
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_type = :client_type";

    //Prepare and Execute Query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);    
    $stmt->bindParam(':client_type', $type);
    $stmt->execute();
    //echo 'Here: ' .$stmt;
    //$rows = $stmt->fetch();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($rows as $row)
    {
        echo "ClientID: ".$row['client_id'] . " ";
        echo "Name: ".$row['client_name'] . " ";
        echo "Title: ".$row['client_title'] . " ";
        echo "Client Type: ".$row['client_type'] . "<br>";
    }

    //Display associative array
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($rows) .'<br>';
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    json_encode($rows);
    print_r(json_encode($rows));
}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    echo "There was a problem executing the Query: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

Further if i try to check what is the response that i am getting using alert(), it shows: `[object HTMLDivElement]`

Comment: I have commented all the echoes but the error is still there.

Comment: you have to remove all output that is not json. Look into the command line and see what is outputed there. It should be only a valid json

Comment: I changed the datatype to text instead of JSON in jQuery and it worked. But shows the output as below in my answer. i need to get the data and feed it another element or table.

Comment: no need to do that for your initial problem that has been solved apparently. For the second problem please open another question

Answer (score 0):

Remove the echos with the *pre* tags, those are polluting your output and the result is not a valid JSON anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass `json` type string from php to jQuery, seem some `html` tags in your passed string, remove `foreach` loop and just echo `json_encode($rows);`

Your code should be like this:

```
try
{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practice_db'; //your host and database name here.
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    //Connect to database
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_type = :client_type";

    //Prepare and Execute Query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);    
    $stmt->bindParam(':client_type', $type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($rows);

}
catch (PDOException $ex)
{
    echo "There was a problem executing the Query: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

NOTE: php output should not have any space or empty line at return, for example if php file like below, jQuery json parser got error:

```
<--- here empty line --->

<?php
    echo json_encode($row);
?>

<--- here empty line --->
```

Answer (score 0):

While fetching json from a php page only print json on the page.

Try to remove this part

```
echo'<pre>'; 
print_r($rows).'<br>';
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```html
   $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#display").change(function()
                { var type = document.getElementById('display').value;
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "check1.php",
                        data : {"type":type},             
                        success: function(response)
                        {        
       var aa='';              
       var data = JSON.parse(response); 
        data.forEach(function(d){
        aa+= d+'<br>';
        });
       $('#response').html(aa); 
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
<?php
try
                    {
      $type = $_GET['type'];
                        $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practice_db'; //your host and database name here.
                        $username = 'root';
                        $password = '';

                        //Connect to database
                        $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
                        $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_type = :client_type";

                        //Prepare and Execute Query
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);    
                        $stmt->bindParam(':client_type', $type);
                        $stmt->execute();
                        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
      $ars=null;
                        foreach ($rows as $row)
                        {
       $ars[] = $row['client_name'];
                        }
      print_r(json_encode($ars));
                    }
                    catch (PDOException $ex)
                    {
                        echo "There was a problem executing the Query: " . $ex->getMessage();
                    }
                    ?>
```