# Cannot display JSON data in a table using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I am trying to display data fetched as JSON from MySQL DB using PHP into an HTML element say a table. Below is my code for this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test Ajax</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#display").change(function()
                {
                    var type = document.getElementById('display').value;
                    $.ajax(
                    {
                        //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "DBOperations.php",
                        data : "type=" +type,
                        dataType: "text",  //expect text to be returned                
                        success: function(response)
                        {
                            var tr = $('<tr>');
                            tr.append('<td>' + response.client_id + '<td>');
                            tr.append('<td>' + response.client_name + '<td>');
                            tr.append('<td>' + response.client_title + '<td>');
                            tr.append('<td>' + response.client_type + '<td>');

                            $('#myTable').append(tr);
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                        {
                            alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                            alert(response);
                        }

                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <select id="display" name="clienttype" onchange="showClient(this.value)">
            <option value="">Select a Client:</option>
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
            <option value="C">C</option>
            <option value="D">D</option>
            </select>
            </form>
            <br>
        <table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>ClientID</th>
                <th>ClientName</th>
                <th>ClientTitle</th>
                <th>ClientType</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is what i am getting from php as JSON:

```
[{"client_id":"1","0":"1","client_name":"asdf","1":"asdf","client_title":"asdf","2":"asdf","client_type":"a","3":"a"}]
```

Besides if i set the datatype in AJAX to json, it displays the error as in this question:
[how to remove parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529435/how-to-remove-parsererror-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0?noredirect=1#comment78019593_45529435)

So i keep it as either html or text which at least displays the response wtihout the error. but i need to format the response and feed it to another element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    $.ajax(
                        {
                            //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "DBOperations.php",
                            data : {"type :" +type},
                            dataType: "text",  //expect text to be returned                
                            success: function(response)
                            {
      var data = response.d;
                                var tr = $('<tr>');
                                tr.append('<td>' + data .client_id + '<td>');
                                tr.append('<td>' + data.client_name + '<td>');
                                tr.append('<td>' + data.client_title + '<td>');
                                tr.append('<td>' + data.client_type + '<td>');
    
                                $('#myTable').append(tr);
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                            {
                                alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
                                alert(response);
                            }
    
                        });
    
try this one.
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're expecting a JSON string back from server then you should put `dataType: "json"` in your AJAX request. And second, your `success` callback function should be like this:

```
success: function(response){
    var tr = $('<tr>');
    tr.append('<td>' + response[0].client_id + '<td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + response[0].client_name + '<td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + response[0].client_title + '<td>');
    tr.append('<td>' + response[0].client_type + '<td>');
    $('#myTable').append(tr);
}
```

#### Update(1):

Based on [**the question link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529435/how-to-remove-parsererror-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0) you shared, it's clearly visible that you're creating and outputting json string in the wrong way, your PHP and AJAX code should be like this:

**PHP code:**

```
try{
    $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=practice_db'; //your host and database name here.
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    //Connect to database
    $conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_type = :client_type";

    //Prepare and Execute Query
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);    
    $stmt->bindParam(':client_type', $type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($rows);
}catch (PDOException $ex){
    echo "There was a problem executing the Query: " . $ex->getMessage();
}
```

**AJAX code:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "DBOperations.php",
    data : "type=" + type,
    dataType: "json",         
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response, function(key,value) {
            var tr = $('<tr>');
            tr.append('<td>' + value.client_id + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + value.client_name + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + value.client_title + '<td>');
            tr.append('<td>' + value.client_type + '<td>');

            $('#myTable').append(tr);
        }); 
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
        alert('error: ' + textStatus + ': ' + errorThrown);
        alert(response);
    }

});
```

Comment: if i change the datatype to json, it displays an error:parsererror: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0....if  check the response using alert(), it shows [object HTMLDivElement]

Comment: @JunaidFarooq You might be echoing/sending something else apart from the JSON string, check that. Have you changed your `success` callback function as per the proposed solution?

Comment: yes, i have changed the success callback as per your proposed solution but it doesn't work. you can check my PHP code and the related JSON error by following the link provided.

Comment: @JunaidFarooq Where's your PHP code? I don't see any link related your PHP page. By the way, have you checked whether you're `echo`ing something else or not apart from *that* json string?

Comment: check at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529435/how-to-remove-parsererror-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-json-at-position-0?noredirect=1#comment78020827_45529435

Comment: @JunaidFarooq I've updated my answer. Please see the **Update(1)** section of my answer. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.